# My two different controllers don't have the same button recognition ingame

Tags: steam, controllers

I would like to definitely solve a problem with controllers configuration when I play local games with friends on my PC.

I have different controllers (not Xbox controllers but various and random PC controllers).

**The problem I have is that when I launch a game, if the default key to jump is the physical "A" button on my controller 1 in a given game, it will be the physical "B" button with my controller 2 in the same game for example.**

And it is a little annoying because in some games it is just not possible to change the input by the options. And then when I try to explain how to play the explanation will depend on the controller, it is really boring if the game has a lot of control.

Thus, I tried to download x360 ce that emulates an Xbox controller from a random PC controller. I did it to make the game "believe" that he has Xbox controller and by using the emulator I could configure all the thing to make the physical "A" button have the same action in-game for all controllers.

All my games are on Steam, thus I went into the Steam game folder, for example:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Gang Beasts
```

I put the x360ce.exe here. I launch it, it recognizes all my controllers. Then I start it and I configure my controllers to make their buttons coincide in the emulator.

[image]

I push nothing

[image]

I push "A" button on my controller: the light is green, good ! I made sure that all the controllers have the same correspondence: physical A button -> A button in the emulator.

But when I launch the game, nothing changes! The jump button will still be the physical "A" button on my first controller and the physical "B" button on my second one.

How can I solve my problem?

Note: I also checked those options in x360ce (I have read it can fix some issues sometimes) : [image]

Comment: Does the problem only occur with this game?

Comment: Is this true for all games? What game is it? Are you using big picture mode? Do you have any other programs running that deal with non-steam controllers? Are you plugging both controllers in at the same time?

Comment: Just a quick check! (I'm sure you've done this) Are you running the controller emulator in Admin privileges? Are you running it before you run the game? And, is the games primary executable (.exe) in the Gang Beasts root folder, or is it nested under another folder?

Answer (score 2):

The x360ce.exe does not work with all games. I recommend you look for the most updated drivers you find from the controls. It has happened to me with newer drivers that take a configuration very similar to the xbox controls. You could try, maybe this solves your problem. You also have the option of looking for another emulator of controls of xbox360. The x360ce is good but it is not the only one, try with another.

Comment: Something similar happened to me a long time ago. I solved it with a updated joystick drivers. Maybe by updating one you get the same buttons as the other

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually x360ce recognizes well and interpret well the inputs. Thus it is probably a problem with the "communication" between x360ce and the game. So if I understand well you advise me to update the controllers drivers (I hope I will find drivers on internet because some of my controller are quite old even if they work fine !). Can you advise me another "good" emulator (like one that works with enough games). Also, are you sure I putted the x360ce in the good steam folder ? Because I wasn't sure of that.

Answer (score 1):

x360ce is probably not going to work for games launched through Steam if you just drop it into Steam's installation directory -- it's supposed to be in the directory of the game itself so that it's xinput*.dll can be loaded and then it can use the configuration you have setup. This is because Windows can/will automatically load .dll's that are in the same folder as an executable, considering them to be included with it. Part of [SafeDLLSearchMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx) apparently (knew this happened, but never knew what the name was, lol).

Best idea would be to setup x360ce for each game...which obviously would not be ideal, but is likely what's going to be needed.

You could try messing around in Big Picture -> Settings (gear icon) -> Controller Settings turning some of the support on/off, but it's really not likely that this will allow the program to work just by being in Steam's own directory.

There are a few [alternatives to](https://alternativeto.net/software/x360ce/) x360ce, the most notable of which to me is [Durazno](https://github.com/KrossX/Durazno), which is an open-source XInput to XInput (XBox 360 controller) wrapper that lets you customize them; sounds like a slightly-weaker x360ce from that description, but it may do the trick for you.